# Cómo Incremento o decremento de número en un input?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, json

Estoy realizando un formulario de ventas.
en eso tengo un `input` con dos botones a su derecha e izquierda, y quiero aumentar y reducir la cantidad de 1 en 1, sabiendo que el `input` debe de estar restringido para las números menores que 1 (cero y negativos excluidos), por si los ingresan manualmente y a las ves debe de multiplicarse el `precio` por la `cantidad` para dar el `importe` con `javascript` o `json`.

Mi código

```html
<table border ="1">
  <tr>
    <td> Producto </td>
    <td> Precio </td>
    <td> Cantidad </td>
    <td> Importe </td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
      <td> Inka Cola de 350ml x1 </td>
      <td> 5.20 </td>
      <td>  
      <span class="input-group-btn"> 
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type="button">-</button> 
      </span> 
      <input type="text" style="width:50px;text-align: center;" id="contador" class="form-control" value="1">
     <span class="input-group-btn"> 
       <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type="button">+</button> 
      </span> 
      </td>
      <td> 
      <input type="text" style="width:50px;text-align: center;" value="5.20" disabled> 
     </td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Cómo Incrementar o decrementar la cantidad de un número en un input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Acá te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- Se puede cambiar el contador interactuando con los botones de
  incremento y decremento.
- Se pueden cambiar el valor del contador modificando directamente
  el input.
- Si el contador es inválido entonces se modifica automáticamente
  al valor previamente válido.
- Solamente permite valores numéricos y mayores que 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
        <td>Importe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inka Cola de 350ml x1</td>
        <td>5.20</td>
        <td>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type="button">-</button>
          </span>
          <input
            type="text"
            style="width:50px;text-align: center;"
            id="contador"
            class="form-control"
            value="1"
            min="1"
          />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type="button">+</button>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            id="importe"
            type="number"
            style="width:50px;text-align: center;"
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var sumar = document.getElementById("mas");
      var restar = document.getElementById("menos");
      var contador = document.getElementById("contador");
      var importe = document.getElementById("importe");
      var valorBase = 5.20;
      var prevValue;

      function calcular() {
        var value = contador.value;
        var isValid = /^[1-9][0-9]*$/.test(value);

        if (!isValid) {
          contador.value = prevValue;
        } else {
          prevValue = value;
        }

        importe.value = Number.parseFloat(contador.value * valorBase).toFixed(2);
      }

      sumar.onclick = function() {
        contador.value = Number(contador.value) + 1;
        calcular();
      };

      restar.onclick = function() {
        contador.value = Number(contador.value) - 1;
        calcular();
      };

      contador.onchange = function() {
        calcular();
      };

      contador.onkeyup = function() {
        if (contador.value === "") {
          return;
        }
        calcular();
      };

      calcular();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar la propieda `STEP`

Definición y uso
El atributo step especifica el intervalo entre números legales en un elemento .

Consejo: El atributo de paso se puede usar junto con los atributos máximo y mínimo para crear un rango de valores legales.

Nota: El atributo de paso funciona con los siguientes tipos de entrada: número, rango, fecha, fecha y hora, fecha-hora local, mes, hora y semana.

```js
    jQuery('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter('.quantity input');
    jQuery('.quantity').each(function() {
      var spinner = jQuery(this),
        input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
        btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
        btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
        min = input.attr('min'),
        max = input.attr('max');

      btnUp.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue >= max) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue + 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

      btnDown.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue <= min) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue - 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

    });
```

```css
.quantity {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number]
{
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.quantity input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  line-height: 1.7;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="quantity">
  <input type="number" min="0"  step="1" value="0">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mas() {
var contador = document.getElementById("contador").value;
var int = parseInt(contador, 10);
document.getElementById("contador").value = int +1;

}

function menos() {
      var cont = document.getElementById("contador").value;
      var counterValue = parseInt('cont',10);
      var NewCont = (counterValue) ? counterValue - 1: 0;
 document.getElementById("contador").value = NewCont;
}
```

```html
<table border ="1">
  <tr>
    <td> Producto </td>
    <td> Precio </td>
    <td> Cantidad </td>
    <td> Importe </td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
      <td> Inka Cola de 350ml x1 </td>
      <td> 5.20 </td>
      <td>  
      <span class="input-group-btn"> 
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type='submit' onclick="menos()">-</button> 
      </span> 
      <input type="text" style="width:50px;text-align: center;" id="contador" class="form-control" value="1">
     <span class="input-group-btn"> 
       <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type='button' onclick="mas()">+</button> 
      </span> 
      </td>
      <td> 
      <input type="text" style="width:50px;text-align: center;" value="5.20" disabled> 
     </td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

Debería funcionar así.

Comment: funciona, pero se va hasta los negativos cuando se da en menos (-)

Comment: agregue la validacion

Answer (score 0):

Primero, no necesitas un JSON.

En cuanto al incremento / decremento de un *input* con Vainilla JS, recoges su valor cada vez que se pulse uno de los botones para incrementar o decrementar el mismo y lo vuelves a colocar después de los controles y / o modificaciones pertinentes, por ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .counter-group button, 
        .counter-group input {
            display: inline-block;
            margin : 5px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
    
        function $(id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function increase()
        {
            $('counter').value = parseInt($('counter').value) + 1;
        }

        function decrease()
        {
            var counterValue = parseInt($('counter').value);
            var newCounterValue = (counterValue)
                ? counterValue - 1
                : 0;

            $('counter').value = newCounterValue;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="counter-group">
        <button onclick="increase()">+</button>
        <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="0" id="counter">
        <button onclick="decrease()">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

En este ejemplo el javascript solo controla los botones.

Se asocia un evento clic a cada uno de los botones, para añadir 1 solo se recoge el valor del *input* y se le añade 1, volviendo a colocarlo. Para restar, como se debe controlar que no se añadan número negativos se establece una *validación del valor recogido* para que nunca sea inferior a 0 (en cuanto al valor controlado con estos botones).

Ahora fijémonos en los atributos HTML5 del *input*. Es de tipo *number*, para que no acepte por ejemplo letras, tiene un *step* de 1 (es el valor de incremento / decremento admitido y es 1 por defecto, aunque no añadamos el atributo) y un valor mínimo de 0. Estos atributos no afectan en nada al código JS que añadí, pero el *input* debe ser de tipo *number* y esto adicionalmente le añade unos controles internos para incrementar / decrementar su contenido (coloca el ratón sobre el *input* para que se muestren.

Ahora pasemos a controlar el ingreso de cantidades directamente en el *input*. Puedes usar un evento que controle la perdida del foco (para introducir un número se selecciona el input, al salir puedes hacer las validaciones necesarias).
Como tenemos un *input* de tipo número solo puedes escribir números, también negativos.

Usamos el [evento blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur).

Sustituye el inputu del ejemplo por este otro:

```
<input type="number" min="0" value="0" id="counter" onblur="handleIntro()">
```

Y añades la función correspondiente al javascript. Internamente solo *parsea* a número lo que se introdujo, por ejemplo pasa 034 a 34 y evita negativos, poniéndolos a 0.

```html
Ejemplo completo:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .counter-group button, 
        .counter-group input {
            display: inline-block;
            margin : 5px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
    
        function $(id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function increase()
        {
            $('counter').value = parseInt($('counter').value) + 1;
        }

        function decrease()
        {
            var counterValue = parseInt($('counter').value);
            var newCounterValue = (counterValue)
                ? counterValue - 1
                : 0;

            $('counter').value = newCounterValue;
        }

        function handleIntro()
        {
            var counterValue = parseInt($('counter').value);

            var newCounterValue = (counterValue < 0)
                ? 0
                : counterValue;

            $('counter').value = newCounterValue;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="counter-group">
        <button onclick="increase()">+</button>
        <input type="number" min="0" value="0" id="counter" onblur="handleIntro()">
        <button onclick="decrease()">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aun te quedaría controlar el que se introduzcan operaciones en el imput, por ejemplo, permite 2+12 y produce un NaN y el calculo de valores, asociando un evento *onchange*.